# Error when Merging worksheets from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, merge

I need to write a macro that merges all the sheets from the ISOHODataCopy1.xls workbook to the zmastertablestest1.xlsm workbook. They are the only two files in the Source_and_Master_Data folder. I have been using this code:

```
Sub GetISOSheets()
Path = "C:\Users\turner\Desktop\Source_and_Master_Data\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
Do While Filename <> ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Next Sheet
Workbooks(Filename).Close
Filename = Dir()
Loop

End Sub
```

This vba code successfully merges the worksheets to the master workbook, but two error boxes appear.

1. File not found: 'C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\VBF10tmp
2. Run-time error '1004': Copy method of worksheet class failed.

The error occurs because of this line of code:
    Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

I want to be able to run this macro and another macro at the same time, but the errors prevent this. **How can I resolve these errors? **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was receiving the two errors because the master workbook was in the same folder as the ISOHODataCopy1.xls workbook, so it was trying to copy itself essentially. When I took the master workbook out of the folder the macro worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know if your source data excel files contains defined names?  The MS help below might gives you a clue:

[Microsoft helps](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q210684)

Answer (score 0):

Try **replacing** :

```
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Next Sheet
```

**with** :

```
For Each thisSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
thisSheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Next thisSheet
```

Comment: After I changed the code I received this error: Run-time error '424': Object required. The error occurs at this line of code: Worksheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).

Comment: My mistake, poor copy-paste'ing skills.